# SQL Server inject trigger ignored?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

One of my customer's website had been getting injection attack (inserting ads in emails) and at that time I didn't know how to handle the attack so I set trigger on update and delete to send me an email so I would know ads were added to table. However, I did not receive any email when values got changed.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIG_DEL] 
ON [dbo].[A]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)

    SET @str = CONCAT('Someone is trying to delete A table at ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

    EXEC [msdb].[dbo].sp_send_dbmail  
                @profile_name = 'A_Email',
                @recipients = 'abc@def.com;',
                @subject = 'UPDATE ALERT',
                @body = @str
END
```

This is my trigger and it works fine when I test it. Is there any way to avoid trigger? I just want to know how the attacker avoided the trigger, out of curiosity.

Comment: You are going to need to expand on your question on what is needed and to please provide some example code. Is your focus more on why the trigger isn't working (which you need to provide code for, if so) or are you just wanting to see if there is a way to avoid a trigger completely? Are you wanting to be notified of when records are added to check for malicious attempts from an outside user? Or are you wanting to know proper secure TSQL and application programming guidelines to implement code that protects against SQL Injection?

Comment: @DtechNet Thanks for the advice. I just added a bit more detail. I have been just curious how he could have avoided the trigger.

Comment: @MinLee there are a few you things you need to check. You cannot have an **INSTEAD OF DELETE** trigger if the table has a referential relationship specifying a cascading action on DELETE. Same apply for the **INSTEAD OF UPDATE** trigger, this is, if the table has a referential relationship specifying a cascading action on UPDATE.

Comment: Explain why you assume that this injection attack is related to deletions of a particular table. Based on what you have written, I would say your assumption is not correct. Your trigger avoids a very specific action - an injection attack can do many other things besides deleting rows from this particular table.

Comment: I think you have the wrong angle. What you should be doing, is reviewing all your SQL statements and change them to prepared statements as the cause of the injection is likely string concatenated SQL statements without proper escaping. Though escaping every input properly can work, it is the least recommended way of avoiding SQL injection. Please review the [OWASP SQL Injection cheat sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md) for more details.